# Excel - VBA - Search for a specific value within a cell

Tags: excel, vba, cell

Is it possible to search for a specific value in a column?

I want to be able to search all of the cells in column "B" and look for the 'word' "pip" in it (without being case sensitive). I've got everything else, just need to know if this is possible or how it can be done.

My Current code looks as follows:

```
Sub A()

    ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Data")

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws1.Name = "pip"

    ws.Activate
    Row = 2

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        If (Cells(i, 2).Value = (HAS pip IN IT) Then 'This is the part that i'm struggling with

            Copied = ws.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 17)).Value 'If possible, this would cut and paste so it deleted the original
            ws1.Activate
            ws1.Range(Cells(Row, 1), Cells(Row, 17)).Value = Copied

        Row = Row + 1

        ws.Activate

        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

Edit: Just to clarify, the value in column B will never just be "pip". It will be a full sentence but if it contains "pip" then i would like the IF function to work.

Comment: Look into Instr()

Comment: Look into `Find` (faster than looking at each cell).  Is Feas a Spanish word?

Answer (score 1):

`Find` and `FindNext` work nicely (and quickly!)

```
    '...
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    Set copyRange = ws.Range("B1:B1500").Find("pip", , , xlPart)

    If Not copyRange Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = copyRange.Address
        Do
            ws2.Range(Cells(Row, 1), Cells(Row, 17)).Value = Intersect(copyRange.EntireRow, ws.Columns("A:Q")).Value
            Row = Row + 1
            Set copyRange = Range("B1:B10").FindNext(copyRange)

        Loop While copyRange.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
    '...
```

Comment: You could remove the `Not copyRange Is Nothing` from the `Loop While`  as  you're not changing a value in the range `B1:B1500` then `copyRange` will always be something (providing it's found something in the first place) - so just check for when it gets back to the first address.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook good point! - thanks for that. I've updated the answer

Comment: I'm having a little trouble incorporating this into my Macro. If i copy and paste and make sure all of the variables are set i still get a Type mismatch error at `= Intersect(copyRange.Row,`(The .Row part). Any idea why this is?

Comment: @Dullspark, that should have been `EntireRow`, I've edited now. However, if you update your question to include all of your code then I could do a much better job of making sure this code is compatible

Comment: @CallumDA, I've updated my initial post to include all of my code. I was also thinking about it last night and it would be very useful if instead of copying Columns A:Q and pasting them, it would cut and paste. Is this possible?

Comment: Just wondering if you have any ideas towards this? No worries if not :)